# Facebook page style urls in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

How would I write a route in Asp.Net mvc to handle a url like this one for a Facebook page:

http://graph.facebook.com/http://codedojoboise.com/

I tried this route but get a 400 Bad Request error when I try to run it.

```
 routes.MapRoute(

            "LinkPreview",
            "LinkPreview/{path}",
            new {controller = "LinkPreview", action = "Get"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters : and / are being treated like parameter separators and so the route isn't matching. Try LinkPreview/{*path} which will tell it to use all the following characters as part of the parameter.

Comment: I tried the {*path}, which is a more correct route, but it's still blowing up if I include "http://" in the url

Comment: Looked into Darin's links and it's being blocked by ASP at quite a deep level.

Comment: Looked into Darin's links and ":" being blocked by ASP at quite a deep level. You have 3 choices here. As Darin suggests you could Base64 encode it (which looks ugly), use the "requestPathInvalidCharacters" attribute as mentioned in the first link Darin posted (security issues) or if you can assume you're only going to be previewing http: pages just exclude the "http://" in the url and add it in server side. If not using Base64 you'll still need to use {*path} to deal with the "/"

Comment: So in the end I decided to just leave off the protocol portion of the URL. My initial code block was missing the "{*path}" so this helped

Answer (score 0):

Handling such characters in ASP.NET is a real PITA. You may checkout [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) or [base64 encode it](http://gathadams.com/2009/01/06/allowing-special-characters-forward-slash-hash-asterisk-etc-in-aspnet-mvc-urls/).